# Remove duplicates dictionaries from list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json

I want to remove duplicates dictionaries from list of dictionaries. I am trying to make configurable code to work on any field instead of making field specific.

**Input Data**

```
dct = {'Customer_Number': 90617174, 
       'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [12177218280.0]}, 
                        {'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [12177218280.0]}],
       'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 
                  'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']},
                 {'Email_Type': 'Primary', 
                  'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}]
      }
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{'Customer_Number': 90617174, 
                'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 
                           'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}], 
                'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 
                                  'Phone': [12177218280]}]}



**Code tried:**

    res_list = []
    for key,value in address_dic.items():
        if isinstance(value,list):
            for i in range(len(value)):
                if value[i] not in value[i + 1:]:
                   res_list.append(value[i])
    
    dic.append((res_list))


**Output Getting**

    type: [[{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}, {'Email_Type': 'alternate', 'Email': ['samance@gmail.com', 'saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}], [], [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [12177218280.0]}, {'Phone_Type': 'work', 'Phone': [nan]}, {'Phone_Type': 'home', 'Phone': [2177218280.0]}], []]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to dedupe lists:

```
def dedupe_list(lst):
    result = []
    for el in lst:
        if el not in result:
            result.append(el)
    return result

def dedupe_dict_values(dct):
    result = {}
    for key in dct:
        if type(dct[key]) is list:
            result[key] = dedupe_list(dct[key])
        else:
            result[key] = dct[key]
    return result
```

#### Test it:

```
deduped_dict = {'Customer_Number': 90617174, 
                'Email': [{'Email_Type': 'Primary', 
                           'Email': ['saman.zonouz@rutgers.edu']}], 
                'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 
                                  'Phone': [12177218280]}]}


dedupe_dict_values(dct) == deduped_dict
## Out[12]: True
```

Comment: What is deduped_dict ?? getting error. I couldn't see if we are using anywhere

Comment: @NaveenGupta it was in your explanation. I inserted it again.